# Bitcoin Newbie Explaination Mining

Tags: bitcoind

Now if the question is stupid forgive me.

From what i have understood so far( i could be wrong )

1. Bitcoin is a digital currency service.

Q : What is difference between `coinbase.com`,`blockchain.info` and thousand other sites who give me a unique bitcoin address upon registration ? Also are those `bitcoin address` unique globally or per site ?

2. You can earn money by bitcoin mining ( letting a software solve some complex mathematical problems in your computer)

Q : why do we need to solve a problem ? cant it have like a database which checks id/password combination like paypal and others on a server ?

Comment: I flagged this is a duplicate because of your second question.  As for your first question, you should do a little more research on your own.  You clearly don't have a good concept of Bitcoin yet.  It might be smart to check out https://bitcoin.org first, and then post specific questions you have when you need clarification.  Welcome!

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, because two of your three questions are answered in the linked questions comprehensively already, and the third strikes me as a product review question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q : What is difference between coinbase.com,blockchain.info and thousand other sites who give me a unique bitcoin address upon registration ?

These websites are competing web wallet providers. You can also use a mobile wallet or a desktop wallet. bitcoin.org has a list of good options.

> Also are those bitcoin address unique globally or per site ?

Each generates their own addresses, but you can send money to someone who uses a different wallet provider by sending it to one of their addresses.